# Multiple Constraints for Genetic Algorithm

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have an optimization function that is doing a sort of data mining by filtering criteria to find an optimal solution.

```
stat_arb = function(data = data_subset_test,
                kurt_lower,
                kurt_upper,
                skew_lower,
                skew_upper,
                mean_lower,
                mean_upper,
                sd_lower,
                sd_upper,
                acf_lower,
                acf_upper,
                min_row = 3000)
```

I have many upper and lower values for each, and want to front-load the constraint to make sure the GA is not calculating the function if lower > upper. I worry that using a penalization function within my function will take much more energy to find optimal because of the number of variables, most solutions will not satisfy my constraints. Is there a way to do this with `ga()` or `nsga2()` in R? Any help is appreciated.